# How many ways execute Stored procedure will be executing

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

**procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DOUBLEN (N IN OUT number) IS
BEGIN
    N := N * 2;
END;
```

for above procedure executing purpose i wrote follow pl/sql code

```
DECLARE
    R INT;
BEGIN
    R := 7;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BEFORE CALL R IS: ' || R);
    DOUBLEN(R);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('AFTER CALL R IS: ' || R);
END;
```

My question is there is any method to execute my Procedure.Let me know please

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It is working fine for me?

Comment: @Armuni any another method is there to execute my stored procedure.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to know? Why would you need another way of executing the procedure?

Comment: because if this process will ok for small stored procedure.if you write large stored procedure it critical to execute.so I'm searching another way

Comment: Why would that bei critical for large procedures?

Comment: critical means it may take much time to write executing procedure

Comment: That really depends on your procedure. There is no alternative to call a stored procedure. If the execution of a procedure takes to much time, then rewrite the procedure, don't blame the way of calling.

Comment: what is the alternative way to rewrite my procedure.let me know please

Comment: It is depending on what you want to achieve, how you can rewrite your query. Please edit your question and make clear what exactly you want to achieve. If you just want to know how to make some random procedure better, then there is no answer and this question should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure proc_in_out
 (n in out number)
 as 
 begin
 dbms_output.put_line('value of n before manipulation'||' '||n);
 n:=n*2;
 dbms_output.put_line('value of n after manipulation'||' '||n);
end proc_in_out;
```

---

```
  set serveroutput on;
     declare 
      n number;
      begin
      n:=2;
      proc_in_out(n);
    end;
```

---

```
    anonymous block completed
    value of n before manipulation 2
    value of n after manipulation 4
```

This will work try this......

Comment: anonymous block completed executing,but out not coming

Comment: Not sure how that answers the question as the code in the question is working fine.